# Error Creating wso2 api-manager using cloudformation

Tags: wso2, aws-cloudformation, wso2-api-manager

When i try to create a stack using cloudformation i get the following error;

PuppetMaster

CREATE_FAILED   Received FAILURE signal with UniqueId i-instanceId

WSO2APIManagerSetup-XXXX

CREATE_FAILED
The following resource(s) failed to create: [PuppetMaster].

WSO2APIMPattern1

Status reason
The following resource(s) failed to create: [WSO2APIManagerSetup]

Where do i check what the actual error was for the PuppetMaster task. Is there any logs on either the PuppetMaster(instanceId), WSO2APIMPattern1 or WSO2APIManagerSetup instances that i can go check?

P.S
Nothing in the cloudtrail logs either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to track down the logs, however i found the issue.
I was populating the WUMUsername and since i don't have a subscription, this was failing. By leaving the WUMUsername and WUMPassword fields blank in the template, everything worked flawlessly.
I suppose i can backtrack to see where in the stack the error would have been thrown, but thats an exercise for another day.